# Syncfusion Globalization and localization

Tags: angular, typescript, syncfusion

I try to implement syncfusion localization for all syncfusion components. 
Reference - syncfusion documentation (https://help.syncfusion.com/angular/gettingstarted/integration-of-globalization-and-localization#getting-started-with-localization)

**app.module.ts**

```
import 'syncfusion-ej-global-all/l10n/ej.localetexts.hr-HR.min.js';
```

**Component**

```
  public locale: any;
  this.locale = "hr-HR";
```

**HTML**

```
<div style="height:65%">
    <ejs-grid id='Grid' #grid
              height="100%"
              [dataSource]='operatorsList'
              [locale]="locale"
              (load)="load($event)" >
              ...
              ..
```

This is translations list I installing by the command:

```
npm install syncfusion-ej-global-all --save
```

[image]

The error I have when I start the application. This file where the error appears is syncfusion file. The same file is selected in the picture above in the list of installed translations.
[image]

What I do wrong?

Comment: Do you have EJAngular2Module?

Comment: No, but right now I try to implement module ref: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ej-angular2
I do everything that reference said and I have a bunch of errors 150 and more. 
For example: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'syncfusion-javascript/Scripts/ej/common/ej.scroller.min' in 'C:\Flexinova\Retail\Source\Development\RBF\AppServerPortal\ClientApp\node_modules\ej-angular2\src\ej'
ERROR in ./node_modules/ej-angular2/src/ej/barcode.component.js

Comment: @Vinod Bhavnani 
Ok, I installed these modules:
npm install ej-angular2 --save
npm install ej-angular2

npm install syncfusion-javascript --save
Now I don't have errors, but I have the same problem from my first question.

Comment: In your app.module did you include the ej2 forRoot line?

Comment: @Vinod Bhavnani Yes, but I have the same error.

Comment: Seems like you have confused between Syncfusion EJ1 and EJ2 Angular components. Please confirm which UI set you want to use in your app.
EJ1: https://help.syncfusion.com/angular/grid/globalizationandlocalization
EJ2:https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/documentation/grid/globalization-and-localization.html#localization